# Can Someone Explain this Loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

How do you store a number into number? You can't do that. But, this code does that, and the code works, perfectly. Can someone please explain it? I am very confused.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0 || num === 1)
    return 1;
  for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    num *= i;
  }
  return num;
}
console.log('factorialize(5) = ', factorialize(5));
```

Comment: `How do you store a number into number?` What do you mean?

Comment: Why not set a break point in the loop and see what actually happens by inspecting the values?

Comment: Its a non recursive factorial function. Typical interview question. What do you not understand about it? Factorial of 1/0 is 1.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Is there a specific line of code that isn't producing an expected result when you debug this?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Bibberty i dont understand this part. num *= i;

Comment: @Muhammad: That's essentially the same as `num = num * i;`  You can look up JavaScript operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: @David i know this but when you pass an argument to the function that num will become a number thats why i am confused

Comment: `num` is a variable. It doesn't _become_ a number.

Comment: @Muhammad: If you know what that operator does then why are you asking what that operator does?  Yes, `num` is a number.  Notice how a number is passed to the function.  The term `num` in this case is called a "variable".  You can assign new values to variables.  You can learn more about variables and how they work in an introductory tutorial on JavaScript.  (In general, if you're looking at code in a language you're not familiar with, introductory tutorials are the first place to go.)

Comment: @David thank you for the info. I know that num is a var called a parameter that is for functions. I was just confused because when you pass an argument the number gets put into that parameter. I imagined this 7 *= 7.

Comment: I added a `console.log` statement to display the output, maybe that will clarify something for you? I would recommend you learn how to debug your code, you can answer most of your own questions that way especially when you are just starting to learn how to program.

Comment: @tkausl thank you for the help my friend.

Comment: ok @Igor i will watch a few videos on that right now!

Comment: Don't think of the parameter being replaced with the literal value it is assigned. A variable is still just a container for a value. The argument is the value that is initially put into that container. But that value can be changed.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you my friend for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

```
num *= i;
```

Just means:

```
num = num * i;
```